# How to change text color on javascript "type"

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I saw this thing were you refresh and the text changes sentences... I got the code and it works but the thing is that I cant get the color to change and the size, nor align it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var sentences = new Array(
"Best site in rsms",
"Please give us game ideas!",
"On currents :))",
"Games for fun?",
"No u",
"Pls",
 "HUH?"
 );
 </script>
```

This is for my head^^^

This is where i want it to go

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(sentences[Math.floor(Math.random()*sentences.length)]);
  </script>
```

Comment: Please don't post code as an image. Use the code sample option of the editor.

Comment: A script tag does not have style. make your code write out an element with the style tage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use CSS for the class you want to apply changes to. Then use `textContent` which is way faster than `innerHTML` as the DOM does not need to be re-parsed and does not pose a security issue for XSS-Injections.

PS: Use single quotes in JS instead of double quotes. Otherwise, you can run into serious issues when working with HTML elements that use double quotes.

```js
let sentences = [
  'Best site in rsms',
  'Please give us game ideas!',
  'On currents :))',
  'Games for fun?',
  'No u',
  'Pls',
  'HUH?'
];
const container = document.querySelector('.sentence')
container.textContent = sentences[Math.floor(Math.random()*sentences.length)];
```

```css
.sentence {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="sentence"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the sentence inside the html element with innerHTML, so you can styling it with css or you just can set the style from your script;
There are explanation, you can run these code snippet

```js
var sentences = new Array(
"Best site in rsms",
"Please give us game ideas!",
"On currents :))",
"Games for fun?",
"No u",
"Pls",
 "HUH?"
 );
const container = document.querySelector(".sentence")
container.innerHTML = sentences[Math.floor(Math.random()*sentences.length)]
container.style = "color: orange"
```

```html
<div class="sentence"></div>
```